# gdb create a file when the application under debugging crashes

Tags: c++, gdb

Debugging a C++ based program (XYZ) that runs indefinitely by listening on a socket and process the data.   I used a test program that read from a list of test-files and send file data via the socket to the C++ based program.

The problem is that XYZ will crash somewhere during the test. I used gdb to run XYZ, would like gdb to create a small file when XYZ crashes. This way I can have test program check the presence of the file to decide whether it should quit.

```
gdb ./XYZ
....
would like it to create a file when XYZ crashes.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you asked for:

```
gdb -ex 'shell rm /tmp/XYZ-crashed' \
  -ex 'run' -ex 'shell touch /tmp/XYZ-crashed' -ex 'quit' ./XYZ
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @employed-russian!